# Android EditText just like Google's Allo messaging app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I want to design edit-text just like [Allo messaging app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.fireball&hl=en) in which on scrolling down the list of messages, message-view is still visible behind that edit text view as shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNJ1j.png).
How to design this type of edit text view?

Answer (score 1):

Aligning the EditText at the bottom in front of the list should be pretty easy.  I would recommend the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </ScrollView>

    <EditText
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You will still have to add elements to your ScrollView or replace it with a ListView, but this should do the trick.

As a side note, elements in the layout file that are added last will be 'in front' of the other views.  Because the last element in our layout is the EditText, it will always hover on top of the ScrollView.

Hope this helps!